# Как отловить обработчик события через Chrome Developer Tools, если он навешивается через jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, javascript, firebug

Если обработчик события навешивается через javascript с использованием addEventListener, то можно легко отловить обработчик события через Chrome Developer Tools, например. Но в случае подключения обработчика через метод $(element).bind(), Chrome Developer Tools показывает первую строку файла jquery.min.js. Как посмотреть непосредственно функцию, вызывающую метод bind на этом элементе?

Comment: Можно ли чуть подробнее? Где ставить breakpoint и как?

Comment: Получилось решить вопрос? Хотелось бы тоже разобраться, как попасть в функцию обработчика, не зная, где она находится. Вариант посмотреть аттрибут "onClick" в properties - явно не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

В хроме: наводите мышь на элемент - из контекстного меню "Просмотр кода элемента" (или F12, вкладка Elements, находите нужный элемент) - в правой части смотрите подпункт Properties, раскрываете первый подпункт в этой части и смотрите значение атрибута (например, onclick), там либо null (не назначено), либо просто function () (значит, где-то в коде задан обработчик, нажимаете правую кнопку, там один пункт show function definition, кидает на объявление этой функции), код в атрибуте элемента видно по самому элементу.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто для отладки, загрузи jquery не min - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js - в этом случае увидишь нужную строку.

Comment: Нет. Мне не нужно видеть jquery.js ни в каком виде. Мне нужно увидеть функцию вызывающую обработчик события через jQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

> а в чем проблема поставить breakpoint
>   на обработчике?
>
> Можно ли чуть подробнее? Где ставить
>   breakpoint и как?

В хроме в веб-инспекторе переходим на вкладку Sources, а под вкладкой Elements есть кнопка со стрелочком, нажав по ней можно выбрать файл в котором находится скрипт. Далее просто нажимаем на номер строки где нужно поставить брейкпоинт. Появляется синий указатель. Всё! Теперь выполнение скрипта будет останавливаться в этом месте.

[image]

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Дело в том, что я не знаю даже название файла, откуда вызывается обработчик.